# Como poner perfectamente alineados de manera horizontal un <p> y un <input> usando html y css dentro de un cuadrado

Tags: html, css

Quiero alinear horizontalmente un elemento `<p>` y un `<input>` dentro de un cuadrado, pero cuando lo hago el elemento `<input>` se pone al lado pero un poco más arriba de lo que yo quiero como se puede ver en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código con el que estoy usando para lograr mi objetivo

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col {
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Grundfos reference</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Facility Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Energy Saving Potential</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Sales company</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Grundfos</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Date</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Los párrafos (`<p></p>`) tienen un espacio adicional que puedes cancelar con `.container p{margin: 0;}`.

Comment: Yo usaría [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) y pondría los `input` dentro de `<p>` tambien, o directamente sacaría los `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

Con un simple `display: flex` a `.container` ya estarían alineados horizontalmente todos sus contenidos.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col {
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Grundfos reference</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Facility Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Energy Saving Potential</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Sales company</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Grundfos</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Author</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Date</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

Pero esto no sería una buena opción de diseños porque hay muchos contenedores en `.container`.

Una opción mejorada podrias ser de esta forma:
Cada contenedor `col` podría tener el párrafo y el input juntos. Entonces a `col` le damos el estilo de alineamiento horizontal.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

 .container .col {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="col">
    <p>Ingrese nombre</p>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
    <p>Párrafo de texto</p>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Falta mucho por hacer, pero esto es solo un ejemplo.